# Recovering Journal - Can't start my Ubuntu

Tags: boot, startup, grubrescue

So I know there's a lot of threads on recovering journal errors and I've tried the solutions but nothing works.

Here's my problem:
My laptop suddenly shut down and when I started it, it gave me a recovering journal error. (Right before the shutdown it said there wasn't enough space on the hard-drive). Now everytime I start my laptop I get the message 'recovering journal' and 'clean xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks' and nothing happens. It's a single boot Ubuntu 19.10 installation.

**I've tried this:**

- Getting into **grub menu - doesn't work** with shift or ESC, I don't get the grub menu only some kind of CLI where I can type but pressing enter does nothing
- I've also tried **booting from USB.** Nothing happens it just stalls and a black screen.

The only thing I can do to get into the BIOS. But I don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
I managed to do a live boot from a USB and delete a lot of files from my Ubuntu installation and that fixed it. It seems that the first port I tried booting the USB from wasn't working.