# recovering journal error

Tags: software-installation

I have a new laptop, a Dell G15 5515 ryzen edition with nvidia geforce rtx 3060. This one comes with w11 and I make a dualbot with ubuntu 21.10. The installation went pretty good but after I install visual studio code and python my screen went black. So I restart the laptop, get the gpu menu, selected ubuntu and finally I get to a black screen with the following message:

```
/dev/nume0np7: recovering journal
/dev/nume0n1p7: clean,196637/12222464 files, 3388363/4862208 blocks
```

I am desperate to understand this error. I tried everything that I found on the internet but nothing worked. I hope somebody could help me and if you know the solution (I know is to much to ask) please try to as specific as possible because I am new at this and is quiet complicated for me. Ty.

Comment: Please don't ask same question more times ... you have already asked the same question in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190641/recovering-journal-cant-start-my-ubuntu ... if you have new information update OP instead,

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand that answer that's why I posted again. Could you expanded please?

Comment: Usually, that menu means that Ubuntu is trying to clean up unused blocks of data. It frees up space and helps performance. If Ubuntu doesn't boot up after it is done with this, then there is a problem.